# How to pass current ID to data delete react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have this code

```
    var html = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = this.props.tables.length; i < len; i++) {

        var id = this.props.tables[i]._id;//._str;
        html.push(
            <div key={id} className="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div className={"thumbnail " + cls}>
                    <div>
                        <a role="button" className="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                            onClick={() => { this.deleteTable(id) } } />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>);
    }
```

which renders a list of "tables", and I am calling a function that removed the data given the `id`. However, mt ID I am passing ends up deleting a different "table" (the last one, always) so clearly I need to somehow save the id with the delete button somehow. How do I do that?

(I used to pass `this.props.tables[i]._id` but it told me that `this.props.tables[i]` is undefined because it was looking at the latest `i`),

This is React with Meteor.

Comment: Can you share your deleteTable code

Comment: It's just 
    deleteTable(id) {
        Meteor.call('tables.deleteTable', id);
    }

where the meteor function does a `Tables.remove(id);` and Tables is `export const Tables = new Mongo.Collection('tables');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by creating a new class `TableDelete` and passing the ID as a param.
So instead of the `<a\>` I have

```
<TableDelete key="del" params={this.props.tables[i]._id} />
```

where `TableDelete` is basically

```
/**
 * Delete a row from the Tables collection, given its id
 * @param id the id of the column
 */
deleteTable(id) {
    Meteor.call('tables.removeTable', id);
}

/**
 * Display the delete button based on the parameters
 */
render() {
    // set the callback depending on the type of delete (row/col)
    var callback = this.deleteTable; //row
    var title = 'Delete Table';

    // display the button
    return (
        <a role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title={title}
            className={'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash'}
            onClick={() => { callback(this.props.params); } } >
        </a>
    );
}
```

and the params are

```
/**
* params: parameters to callback function
*/
TableDelete.propTypes = {
    params: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

I still do not know why this would work but the thing above wouldn't...